# Insert Props in a React class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, media-queries

I'm working with ReactJS and the npm module "react-media-query-hoc", everything is fine when I use functional components to export them with: withMedia(). 
Now I need to use a class component but I'm not doing it right. 
This is from "react-media-query-hoc" docs:

```
import { withMedia } from 'react-media-query-hoc'; 
const MyComponent = ({ media, ...props}) => (
  if(media.tablet || media.mobile) {
    ..
    return (
      <div>
        Mobile and Tablet View
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div>
      Other View
    </div>
  )
);

export const BaseMyComponent = MyComponent;
export default withMedia(MyComponent);
```

I need to transform this to a class Component, please some Help will be great :)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-media-query-hoc

Comment: What did you try? I don't see your code in here at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
import { withMedia } from 'react-media-query-hoc'; 
import React from 'react';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    render(){
        if(this.props.media.tablet || this.props.media.mobile) {
            ...
            return (
                <div>
                    Mobile and Tablet View
                </div>
            )
        }

        return (
            <div>
               Other View
            </div>
        )           
    }
}

export const BaseMyComponent = MyComponent;
export default withMedia(MyComponent);
```

Comment: Yes this works perfect, I was making a mess, THANK YOU